# How do I specify an old JDK compliance in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk1.4

I have a project that I need to be compatible with only up to JDK 1.4. However, I don't have a JDK 1.4 installed on my system (Mac). I get the following warning in Eclipse:

> Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

I have a JDK 8 installed that is compatible but Eclipse is not recognizing it. I don't want anything over 1.4 to enter this project. How do I go about configuring this?

Comment: Is eclipse throwing up an error or is it just a warning??? If it's just a warning you can try to call an API which was introduced after 1.4 and check if eclipse marks it as error, then you will be good to go...

Comment: @AbishekManoharan It's a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project is probably configured to use JDK 1.4.

Since you don't have that one installed, you need to remove it and add the 1.8 you actually have.

- Right click the project and select **"Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path"**
- In the "Java Build Path" option, **remove the "JRE 1.4"**
- Go to "Libraries" -> "Add Library" and **add the JRE 1.8**

Then you can configure the source compatibility to use 1.4 so that new features cannot be used.

- **"Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path"**
- Select **"Java Compiler"**
- Configure **"Source Compatibility" to be "1.4"**

Comment: Not working. I am getting this message and the warning: http://imageshack.com/a/img911/3602/8mOsOd.png

Comment: Somehow Eclipse doesn't think that JDK 8 is compatible with 1.4.

Comment: What part is not working. Were you able to remove JRE 1.4 and add the JRE 1.8? And do you get a new error message now? If so, which one?

Comment: I can remove the old JRE and add the new one but I am still getting the warning.

Comment: I can also specify that 1.4 is compatible in the execution environment pane but I still get the warning.

Comment: Ah actually I am now getting this warning: 
> The JRE container on the classpath is not a perfect match to the 'J2SE-1.4' execution environment

Comment: Moreover, I am allowed to write Java 8 code in the project.

Comment: So now you only have the JRE 1.8 in the "Libraries" section of the build path, right? And if you click on that one and hit "Edit" what "Execution environment" do you have selected? As for disallowing newer code, did you follow the second part of my answer?

Comment: > So now you only have the JRE 1.8 in the "Libraries" section of the build path, right?

Correct.

> And if you click on that one and hit "Edit" what "Execution environment" do you have selected? 

I have specified that 1.4 is compatible with 1.8.

> As for disallowing newer code, did you follow the second part of my answer?

Yes.

Comment: I have the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/khatchad/Common-Eclipse-Refactoring-Framework).

Comment: In the "Libraries" section, select the JRE 1.8 and hit "Edit", then select "JavaSE-1.8" in the "Execution Environment".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81657/discussion-between-raffi-khatchadourian-and-eugenioy).

Comment: This sort of works the way I want it to be setting the execution environment in my plugin to 1.8. I suppose I need to install a 1.4 JRE for this to work properly but I can't even find that old of a JRE for mac.